# Ubuntu wifi issue may be due to partition delete

Tags: networking, dual-boot, partitioning

I kept 110GB unallocated memory using windows disk partitioner to install ubuntu.

**I installed dual-boot ubuntu 16.10 using a USB on my new laptop and was having a happy life with a working Wifi in Ubuntu.**

Then I felt Ubuntu was not installed in the 110GB unallocated memory, so I created a new volume say D-Drive from that unallocated memory. Now Ubuntu didn't boot up instead went to grub. Now I reinstalled ubuntu using the same USB. Now ubuntu works fine but I have below issue:

1. **No wifi connection. I can enable network and enable wifi but no option to select wifi.**

I even disabled secure boot loading. What got messed up? How to fix it? I am trying different ways to fix networking but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. It was the version of ubuntu I was using 16.10. It's pretty messed up. I re-installed a LTS version 16.04 and things are back and awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.10 reached end of life in mid-2017. This means it will no longer receive updates, and repositories are moved to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/.